# Scala travese a collections of case classes with inheritance and solve product with serializable

Tags: scala, class, inheritance, tuples, case

Given the following:

```
sealed trait ProdItem {
   val name: String;
   val price: BigDecimal;
}

final case class Foo( override val name: String = "Apple",
    override val price: BigDecimal = 0.50) extends ProdItem

final case class Bar( override val name: String = "Orange",
    override val price: BigDecimal = 0.35) extends ProdItem

val products = List( Foo, Bar, Foo, Bar)

// products: List[scala.runtime.AbstractFunction2[String,scala.math.BigDecimal,Product with Serializable with ProdItem]] = List(Foo, Bar, Foo, Bar)
```

I can see the list collection is mixed with Products and then Serializable. So it not a simple List[ProdItem]. How do you simply traverse over the elements in products easily?

```
val fullPrice = product.map( x => some_conversion_function(x).price ).sum
```

In other words, how do turn the Tuple back into the leaf case class straightforward?

Is this another example where case class inheritance is stupid?

Comment: You don't have a list of what you want.  You have a list of functions: `List( Foo.apply, Bar.apply, Foo.apply, Bar.apply)`. Instead try `val products = List(Foo(), Bar(), Foo(), Bar())`.

Comment: After I posted, I realised the silly mistake with the parenthesis and constructors. I actually a list of tupled functions in Scala. Anyway thanks for answering my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works.

```
val products = List(new Foo, new Bar, new Foo, new Bar)
val fullPrice = products.map(_.price).sum  // 1.70
```

Consider the following.

```
val foo = Foo()
```

In this example, `Foo` has no name or price, but `foo` does.

When instantiating case classes you have the option of `new Foo`, or the "factory method" `Foo()`.

Comment: You indicate this, but don't say it directly:  saying `val products = List(Foo(), Bar(), Foo(), Bar())` also works.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on jwvh's answer:

`Foo` in `List( Foo, Bar, Foo, Bar)` is the companion object of the class `Foo`, not an instance of this class. Your `products` is a collection of functions (not of `Product with Serializable with ProdItem`!) because

1. Companion objects of case classes extend `AbstractFunctionN`, where `N` is the number of constructor arguments.
2. For `Foo` and `Bar`, the number and types of arguments happen to be the same (if the types of arguments were different, you'd end up with a more complex type, if the numbers were different, you'd likely end up just with `Serializable` or `AnyRef`).
3. `Product with Serializable with ProdItem` is the common supertype of the function *results*.